# SSH Key asks for password

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite, ssh-keys, gitlab

I stuck here now for <strike>like 2 Days</strike> a week.

I've got a CentOs machine with Gitlab4 and gitolite. Everything worked fine for weeks, but suddenly last weekend something strange happend quite all binaries disappeared from the mashine ( like yum, python, ruby, mysql ect. ) i've really no clue how that can happn... After hours of reinstalling and compiling gitlab was working again.

But i cant get the ssh keys between the *gitlab* and *git* user working.
I already deleted and recreated the git user, set again all permissions, recreated the ssh keys, reinstalld gitolite ect. But nothing worked i keep getting the same error.

**git user .ssh folder**

```
-rwx------ 1 git git  557 Mar 27 16:46 authorized_keys
```

**gitlab user .ssh folder**

```
-rw------- 1 gitlab gitlab 1671 Mar 27 16:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab gitlab  406 Mar 27 16:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab gitlab  391 Mar 27 16:50 known_hosts
```

**SSH error:**

```
ssh -vvvT git@localhost
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3p2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3p2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3p2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 132/256
debug2: bits set: 502/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/gitlab/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 505/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa (0x848ba50)
debug2: key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

**The auth log gives me:**

```
Apr  2 10:19:13 venus sshd[15693]: User git not allowed because account is locked
Apr  2 10:19:13 venus sshd[15693]: Failed none for illegal user git from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 56906 ssh2
```

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: have you tried using a new key?

Comment: Answer edited below with the `passwd -u` option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You mention:

```
Apr 2 10:19:13 venus shd[15693]: User git not allowed because account is locked 
Apr 2 10:19:13 venus sshd[15693]: Failed none for illegal user git from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 56906 ssh2
```

[This article](http://grid.ncsa.illinois.edu/ssh/ts_server.html) mentions:

> OpenSSH now checks for locked accounts by default.
>   **On Linux systems, locked accounts are defined as those that have `!!` in the password field of `/etc/shadow`**.
>   **This is the default entry for accounts created with the useradd command**.
>   Even if you are using GSI authentication and do not need local passwords, `sshd` won't let the user login with this message:

```
Too many authentication failures for username
```

> In the `sshd` debugging info it will indicate that the account is locked:

```
User username not allowed because account is locked
```

> Here is some additional information from the sshd Manual:
>
> > Regardless of the authentication type, the account is checked to ensure that it is accessible.
> >     An account is not accessible if it is locked, listed in DenyUsers or its group is listed in DenyGroups.
> >     The definition of a locked account is system dependant.
> >     Some platforms have their own account database (eg AIX) and some modify the passwd field ( "`*LK*`" on Solaris and UnixWare, "`*`" on HP-UX, containing "`Nologin`" on Tru64, a leading "`*LOCKED*`" on FreeBSD and a leading "`!!`" on Linux).
> >     If there is a requirement to disable password authentication for the account while allowing still public-key, then the `passwd` field should be set to something other than these values (eg "`NP`" or "`*NP*`" ).
>
> #### Fix: Replace !! with (for example) NP in /etc/shadow.

---

As mentioned by [jszakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683080/jszakmeister) ([comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664561/ssh-key-asks-for-password/15761971?noredirect=1#comment22577876_15761971)) and [Yongcan-Frank-Lv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219150/yongcan-frank-lv) ([comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664561/ssh-key-asks-for-password/15761971?noredirect=1#comment22403938_15678933)):

```
sudo passwd -u git
```

would be enough to **[unlock the account](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tag/passwd-u-unlock/)**.

Comment: @jszakmeister true, I have added it to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I had git server previously installed and running headless. After I installed GitLab on the same server, GitLab has disabled the "git" user. Dang!

Answer (score 6):

This **exact same issue** was killing me in **gitlab 5.2** (bitnami).

I finally tracked it down in `/var/log/auth.log` which showed:

```
May 28 11:32:10 ml115 sshd[27779]: User git not allowed because account is locked
May 28 11:32:10 ml115 sshd[27779]: input_userauth_request: invalid user git [preauth]
```

After that, it didn't take me long to find that the `git` entry in `/etc/shadow` had a `!` that needed to be replaced with a `*`.

With `*` and all my keys set up, I was able to ssh in from another machine (note that `ssh -vvT git@gitserver` also helps with diagnosis).

`git push -u origin master`

now works.

My system is Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Had, the same issue: was unable to push anything to my git repo and I was thinking it was caused by non standard ssh port and authentication only with keys, but in the end it was all about that `!` in the `/etc/shadow` file.

Answer (score 1):

you should put ~gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys

-rwx------ 1 git git  557 Mar 27 16:46 authorized_keys

-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab gitlab  406 Mar 27 16:45 id_rsa.pub

I can see the size not match, did you add some ssh key option there in authorized_keys?
Also you should check error log of sshd also (eg: /var/log/auth or /var/log/secure etc)

Comment: There are some comments in the auth authorized_keys file, but even if i simply copy the contents of id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys i get the same error.

Comment: login again and check centos's sshd log under /var/log/secure. You are restrict to login for some reason.(eg: permission on .ssh)

Comment: Apr  2 10:19:13 venus sshd[15693]: User git not allowed because account is locked
Apr  2 10:19:13 venus sshd[15693]: Failed none for illegal user git from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 56906 ssh2

Comment: passwd -u <username> will unlock user and do same trick with updating /etc/shadow

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer may work, it may not be the preferred way to go about this.

At least on Ubuntu 12.04, `passwd -u git` will result in this warning:

```
passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock the password of this account.
```

Sounds good... except that the man page for `usermod` warns against using the `-p` option.

```
Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password)
will be visible by users listing the processes.
```

Instead of all of that, calling `passwd -d gitlab` will do the trick by deleting the password for the user (it sets that passwd field to an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution to unlock user: `usermod -p '*' username`