# The git user is unable to execute bundle during GitLab installation

Tags: bash, debian, bundler, gitlab

I am trying to install GitLab on a Debian Wheezy and experiencing an issue I don't understand.

Following the [install guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md) for version 5.0:

- step 1: was run as explained
- step 2: I used rvm (multi-user install) instead (ruby-1.9.3-p392)
- steps 3 to 5: were run as explained (MySQL chosen)
- step 6: everything works fine until the "Install Gems" section, where I get the following error:

```
/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

I run this as my normal user (in the `sudo` and `rvm` groups), and the `git` user is not a `sudo`er.

I think that the line `sudo gem install bundler`, in step 2, does not grant the `git` user to execute bundle properly, but I don't know how to fix this.

I probably did something wrong but cannot figure out what it is, as I tried to respect the standard instructions as close as possible.

Any clue about this? Thanks, I am losing hope...

For information, I have written to the GitLab mailing-list about this problem but did not get any answer. Moreover, last time I asked something similar on ServerFault, I have been advised to post on StackOverflow instead... hence this question :)

Comment: By the way, I did not manage to show the bash line as code, if anyone wants to edit my post...

Comment: Can user `git` execute `bundle`? Where is `bundle` installed?

Comment: When I do `$ which bundle`, I get `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/bundle`. The `git` user has been created with the `--disabled-login` flag and thus I cannot login as `git` to run `bundle`. When I do `$ sudo -u git bundle`, I get `sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory` but my normal user can execute `bundle` even without `sudo`ing it. Does this answer your question? :s Also, thanks for editing my post, didn't think of the `<pre>` tag!

Comment: That must be because `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin`isn't in the path of git. You have various solutions for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/257666/6309 or http://superuser.com/q/98686/141

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your advice. Reading those 2 links, there are plenty of solutions indeed. Many of them suggest to edit the `sudo`ers file with several changes, and those changes are ultimately considered as security mistakes by other people. It seems that running `sudo -i -u git bundle` instead of `sudo -u git bundle` does the trick. Should I go for the `-i` solution or should I edit the `sudo`ers file instead, according to you?

Comment: If you can avoid editing the sudoers file, it is always better. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do `$ which bundle`, I get `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/bundle`.
>   The `git` user has been created with the `--disabled-login` flag and thus I cannot login as `git` to run `bundle`.
>   When I do `$ sudo -u git bundle`, I get

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

That means git user has not /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin in its PATH, and you cannot modify its `.profile` or `.bashrc` because of the `--disabled-login` flag.

> It seems that running **`sudo -i -u git bundle`** instead of `sudo -u git bundle` does the trick

That is the safest route, and will execute the command as git, but will simulate first an initial login, using the `PATH` defined in `.profile` and `.bashrc` of user `root`.
See "[How does `sudo` search the path for executable?](https://serverfault.com/a/259405/783)" for more.

Comment: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin` is not in any `.profile` or `.bashrc` file of `root` or `git` users, so I don't know where it is set... Also, using `-i`, the current directory is `/home/git`  but I need to `cd gitlab` before running `bundle`. Is there a better/cleaner way than doing `sudo -i -u git sh -c 'cd gitlab && bundle'`? It seems hackish to me...

Comment: @JérémieAstori and a `cd gitlab`, followed by a `sudo -i -u git bundle install ...` doesn't work?

Comment: Nop... And if I run `cd gitlab` followed by `sudo -i -u git pwd`, it outputs `/home/git`.

Comment: @JérémieAstori then the `cd && bundle` option you mentioned is worth a shot.

Comment: I will try it. It's odd though, as even the [TroubleShooting Guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide) refers a lot to `sudo -u git bundle`, would there be a better way to edit the `git` user's PATH so that I don't need this weird command eventually?

Comment: @JérémieAstori I agree, editing the path in the `git` account would be ideal.

Comment: Do you know how I could do that? I mean, instead of setting it hardcoded. There are several additions to both my normal and `root` users but nothing for the git user (at the beginning of the `$PATH` variable). Nothing particular in the `sudo`ers file neither...

Comment: @JérémieAstori I am still looking into that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/243346/how-to-run-a-command-as-a-user-whose-login-is-disabled can be a good read on sudo though. Modifyinh root PATH remains the straightforward way: http://askubuntu.com/q/262064

Comment: I am experiencing so many troubles to install GitLab on this ARM board that I will postpone its installation for now. Anyway, the `sudo -i -u git 'cd [...] && bundle install [...]'` works for this particular problem, so I will keep this as a solution and will update this topic if I (or you, maybe!) find a better way to do that. Congrats, you've won your upvote/accepted mention, and thanks above all :-)

Comment: @JérémieAstori You are most welcome. Another similar case (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15761971/6309) would involve "unlocking" the git account. Not ideal either.

Comment: @JérémieAstori that, or the sudoers NOPASSWD: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15861652/6309

Answer (score 0):

On my local machine after upgrade from 6.4 to 7.7 I had such issue.

The compilation of ruby was made under root account.

So need permissions to read compiled ruby and installed bundle.

```
chmod ugo+rx /usr/local/bin/bundle
chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/local/lib/ruby/
```

In production mode You could be more strict.